# Two table joins for one query -- confusing result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute two separate inner table joins in my query to return values from two tables.

```
    SELECT pname, avg(salary)
    FROM project p INNER JOIN department d on p.dnum = d.dnumber
    INNER JOIN employee e ON e.dno = d.dnumber;
```

I'm getting one row in the result set... pname = null, avg(salary) = null.
Result set should contain 11 rows because there are 11 projects in the schema.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `group by`:

```
SELECT pname, avg(salary)
FROM project p INNER JOIN
     department d
     on p.dnum = d.dnumber INNER JOIN
     employee e
     ON e.dno = d.dnumber
GROUP BY pname;
```

In most databases, your version would fail with an obvious syntax error.  MySQL only enforces the ANSI standard if you use the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)).

Comment: Adding the group by pname; clause seems to return 0 rows.

Comment: @Matthew.learn . . . That would be a different problem -- your join conditions would appear to be incorrect.  You may need to ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @onedaywhen . . . I think you misunderstood the comment.  It was about the OP's original query.  I clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Use left outer join instead of inner join
Or can you show me your data tables

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the `department` table in your query?

Does the following query return all the data you need to summarize?

```
SELECT pname, salary
  FROM ( SELECT salary, dno AS dnum FROM employee ) e
       NATURAL JOIN project;
```

If it does, then this might be the summarization you require:

```
SELECT pname, AVG( salary ) AS average_salary
  FROM ( SELECT salary, dno AS dnum FROM employee ) e
       NATURAL JOIN project
 GROUP 
    BY pname;
```